# Calculating wages with different percentage and work hours from total

Tags: calculus, finance, percentages

Hello Dear Mathmaticians,

I've run into a problem with calculating wages for workers.

4 workers are paid a different percentage from a total weekly amount earned on commission.
Every worker worked a different set of hours during the week and must be paid based on work hours.

Here is an  example:

Total amount earned was £3000

Worker A is paid a set percentage of 33% of the total amount but has only worked 16 hours

Worker B is paid is also paid 33% of the total amount but he worked 40 hours

Worker C is paid a set percentage of 15% of the total amount and has worked a total of 20 hours

Worker D is paid a set percentage of 19% of the total amount and has worked a total of 17 hours

So far the math I'm doing was leaves me with fluctuating discrepancies based on worker hours and it doesn't come to the total of 100%, here's the formula I've come up with:

(4Δzy / x )
where 4 is for the number of workers,
Δ is the total amount earned,
z is set percentage for the worker
y is the number of hours worked by the worker
and x is the total number of hours worked by all workers.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please? or at least tell me if this is solvable.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to calculate?  I don't see where you have stated the problem.

Comment: Any reply to the given answer?

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the hourly wage for a given worker you'll want to use the following formula: $$ \frac{Tp}{h} $$ where $T$ is the total amount earned, $p$ is the percent paid to that worker and $h$ is the number of hours worked by that person.

$Tp$ gives the total amount earned by the worker, and dividing by $h$ gives us how much they made on average each hour.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I am trying to combine percentage with hourly wage to get a weekly wage based on the amount of hours worked combined with the percentage that each person would get if they each worked the same number of hours. So if each person worked 8 hours each then the Tp/h calculation would work perfectly however what if the case is that each worker worked a different number of hours would the calculation still work?

Comment: @ToothlessJack If I understand you correctly, this should still work! So if Ann worked 6 hours this week, our total earned was \$3 000 and Ann gets 15%, then $\frac{Tp}{h}$ gives us that Ann made $\frac{3000 \times 0.15}{6} = \$75$ per hour this week. If Craig worked 9 hours that same week and was paid 20%, then Craig would earn $\frac{3000 \times 0.20}{9} = \$66.66$ per hour this week.